# complex table join with filter and using 'like' for columns

Tags: sql-server

I have a complex table that shows and actual and forecast for sales information, with multiple upload dates. I want to be able to join the table on the product ID, while finding the percent error for each product and only using the most recent information. The products are from numerous suppliers, so they all have different names but relate to the same product. For example, product A from two suppliers may be names supplier1_A and supplier2_A, but I want to be able to add these together into one column to find the error. Here is an example of the data:

```
Type     | ID                | DateUpload     |Jan. | Feb. | March
Forecast   Supplier1_Apples       2018-01-01    5      6      5
Actual     Supplier1_Apples       2018-01-01    4      4      5
Forecast   Supplier1_Apples       2018-02-01    5      6      5
Actual     Supplier1_Apples       2018-02-01    4      6      5
Forecast   Supplier2_Apples       2018-02-01    6      6      5
Actual     Supplier2_Apples       2018-02-01    4      4      3
Forecast   Supplier3_Apples       2018-02-01    8      9      5
Actual     Supplier3_Apples       2018-02-01    7      8      5
```

The table I want in the end would look like this

```
ID    | DateUpload  | error_jan...
Apples   2018-02-01   (abs(total_actual - total_forecast))/total_actual
```

Is this join possible to consolidate into one table with all the filters or do I need to create a different table that takes the error for each supplier and then find the average of that? Currently, I am able to join the table based on the IDs to find the error at each ID, but cannot combine them all if they are similar to find the overall error for Apples in this example.

Comment: I am guessing that you want to use GROUP BY - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could join or group any products if there is a fixed pattern to be used. For instance, in your example, `Supplier1_Apples` we can see all products `Apples` has a prefix with the supplierID along with (underscore) as separator. The supplier name and the product names could be changed but the (underscore) will be used in all of them. In that case we can use `CHARINDEX()` function to get the position number of that (underscore), which will help us extract the product ID only.

So, For this we will use `CHARINDEX()`, `LEN()` , and `SUBSTRING()` functions to have something like this :

```
SUBSTRING(ID, CHARINDEX('_',ID,1) + 1,LEN(ID) - CHARINDEX('_',ID,1) + 1)
```

This would give us `Apples` which is our goal. 
From there we can use `GROUP BY` along with `SUM()` to group the results like this :

```
SELECT 
  [Type]
, SUBSTRING(ID, CHARINDEX('_',ID,1) + 1,LEN(ID) - CHARINDEX('_',ID,1) + 1) ID
, DateUpload
, SUM(Jan) Jan
, SUM(Feb) Feb
, SUM(Mar) Mar
FROM test
GROUP BY 
 [Type]
, SUBSTRING(ID, CHARINDEX('_',ID,1) + 1,LEN(ID) - CHARINDEX('_',ID,1) + 1)
, DateUpload
```

This would give us :

```
|     Type |     ID | DateUpload | Jan | Feb | Mar |
|----------|--------|------------|-----|-----|-----|
|   Actual | Apples | 2018-01-01 |   4 |   4 |   5 |
|   Actual | Apples | 2018-02-01 |  15 |  18 |  13 |
| Forecast | Apples | 2018-01-01 |   5 |   6 |   5 |
| Forecast | Apples | 2018-02-01 |  19 |  21 |  15 |
```

Now it's only of matter of using it as sub-query, and you can go further from there.

an example :

```
SELECT 
  ID
, DateUpload 
, error_jan     =   ( ABS(TotalJunActual -  TotalJunForecast) ) / TotalActual
FROM (
SELECT 
    ID 
,   DateUpload
,   SUM(ABS(CASE WHEN [Type] = 'Actual' THEN JAN ELSE 0 END)) TotalJunActual
,   SUM(ABS(CASE WHEN [Type] = 'Forecast' THEN JAN ELSE 0 END)) TotalJunForecast
,   SUM(ABS(CASE WHEN [Type] = 'Actual' THEN JAN + Feb + Mar  ELSE 0 END)) TotalActual
,   SUM(ABS(CASE WHEN [Type] = 'Forecast' THEN JAN + Feb + Mar ELSE 0 END)) TotalForecast
FROM (
SELECT 
  [Type]
, SUBSTRING(ID, CHARINDEX('_',ID,1) + 1,LEN(ID) - CHARINDEX('_',ID,1) + 1) ID
, DateUpload
, SUM(Jan) Jan
, SUM(Feb) Feb
, SUM(Mar) Mar
FROM test
GROUP BY 
 [Type]
, SUBSTRING(ID, CHARINDEX('_',ID,1) + 1,LEN(ID) - CHARINDEX('_',ID,1) + 1)
, DateUpload
) D
GROUP BY 
    ID 
,   DateUpload
) C
```

results :

```
|     ID | DateUpload | error_jan |
|--------|------------|-----------|
| Apples | 2018-01-01 |  0.076923 |
| Apples | 2018-02-01 |  0.086956 |
```

[Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/26324/3)

Answer (score 1):

- You need to split the ID to remove supplier from ID
- Then use CTEs or subqueries to filter out Actual and forcast data
- Then join both CTEs on Id and DateUploaded
- Then group by Id and DateUploaded
- Now you know how to calculate the Error column value, I did it for JAN and hope it works.

**Data preparation**

```
declare @mytable as table(
Type varchar(10),
ID varchar(50),
DateUploaded datetime,
JAN decimal
)

insert into @mytable values ('Forecast', 'Supplier1_Apples','2018-01-01',5)
insert into @mytable values ('Actual', 'Supplier1_Apples','2018-01-01',4)

insert into @mytable values ('Forecast', 'Supplier1_Apples','2018-02-01',5)
insert into @mytable values ('Actual', 'Supplier1_Apples','2018-02-01',4)

insert into @mytable values ('Forecast', 'Supplier2_Apples','2018-02-01',6)
insert into @mytable values ('Actual', 'Supplier2_Apples','2018-02-01',4)

insert into @mytable values ('Forecast', 'Supplier3_Apples','2018-02-01',8)
insert into @mytable values ('Actual', 'Supplier3_Apples','2018-02-01',7)
```

**Query:**

```
;With ForecastCTE AS
(
    Select 
    substring(ID, CHARINDEX('_',ID)+1, LEN(ID)) as Id, 
    DateUploaded,
    JAN
    From @mytable
    Where Type = 'Forecast'
),
ActualCTE AS
(
    Select 
    substring(ID, CHARINDEX('_',ID)+1, LEN(ID)) as Id, 
    DateUploaded,
    JAN
    From @mytable
    Where Type = 'Actual'
)
Select 
    F.Id,
    F.DateUploaded,
    (abs((SUM(A.JAN) - SUM(F.JAN))/SUM(A.JAN))) AS error_jan
from ForecastCTE F
INNER join ActualCTE A on F.ID = A.ID and F.DateUploaded = A.DateUploaded
Group by F.Id,F.DateUploaded
```

**Output :**

```
Id      DateUploaded                error_jan
Apples  2018-01-01 00:00:00.000     0.250000
Apples  2018-02-01 00:00:00.000     0.266666
```

Comment: I don't believe there is a need for a CTE.

Comment: Another approach is using sub-queries as I mentioned in the answer. but I prefer to use CTE for readability and encapsulation. I would like to learn different approach to solve this requirement, if any.